# Getting an error when starting Samba

Tags: samba4, zentyal

I am using Zentyal 5 on my original samba DC (containing Samba Version 4.6.7-Ubuntu). I am trying to join another DC of the same version to this existing DC, and I keep getting this error when I try to start samba:

**ON EXISTING DC**

`Error setting gidNumber on group CN=dns_EXAMPLE,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com
 There was an erro updating LDAP: The server cannot find an object specified in 
 the request`

**ON JOINING DC**

`Could not find machine account in secrets database: Failed to fetch machine account password for EXAMPLE from both secrets.ldb (Could not find entry to match filter: '(&(flatname=EXAMPLE)(objectclass=primaryDomain))' base: 'cn=Primary Domains': No such object: dsdb_search at`

I have checked permission on /var/lib/samba and sub folders. Have also run `samba-tool dbcheck --fix`

What could be the problem? And what more can I try?